# PHP - How to read a private XML file?

Tags: php, xml, permissions, simplexml

I have a script on "domain 1" which performs a simplexml_load_file on an XML file on "domain 2" like so:

```
$url = 'domain2.com/file.xml';
$xml  = simplexml_load_file($url);

$xmlEmail = $xml->xpath("//users/user/email");
$userEmail = implode(", ", (array) $xmlEmail);
```

However, this XML file contains private info about users. I don't want it to be directly accessible. Domain 2 will also be different according to the user so I can't filter by actual domains or IP's I'm afraid.

**Is it possible to set permissions to make it non accessible to the public, but somehow still readable via the simplexml call? Any alternative methods perhaps?**

Comment: i think the only way to do this is with htaccess by restricting access to some ips of your choice (in this case, the domain1's IP for example)

Answer (score 1):

Add following to your `.htaccess` file, that resides in the same folder as `file.xml`:

```
<Files file.xml>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from domain2.com
</Files>
```

This will tell your web server to disable access to this file, except if request comes from `domain2.com`.

UPDATE:

According to what question owner told, this xml file will be accessed from different domains. In this case the only reasonable option I might think of is a password. *galymzhan* already provided the answer, but I will try extend his answer and to provide a working solution.

Add following to your `.htaccess` file, that resides in the same folder as `file.xml`:

*.htaccess*

```
<Files file.xml>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Access"
    AuthUserFile /full/path/to/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Files>
```

Please note, it's not required to have a shell access to the server. you can upload `.htpasswd` file via ftp, and change it's permissions so it will be not read/write by web server group.

More info about password protection, and some examples, can be found [here](http://www.elated.com/articles/password-protecting-your-pages-with-htaccess/).

Comment: domain2.com will be different according to the user so not sure this will work. Is there simply no way of blocking direct access? but allow access via an external script?

Comment: Short answer : No. Long answer: you can try to achieve this using `.htaccess` as well, but it will be possible to download your file using 3rd party external script.

Comment: The private info is just e-mail addresses and site URL's for customers which is why i'd rather not have it freely available but at the same time, it's nothing of any use to anyone so if using a 3rd party external script is the only way of accessing it, this may be the answer then. Tough one to decide upon...

Answer (score 1):

Set HTTP basic authentication for your web-server on "domain 2". Change the url for XML file like this:

```
$url = 'http://my_username:my_password@domain2.com/file.xml';
$xml  = simplexml_load_file($url);
```

[mod_auth_basic for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_auth_basic.html)

Comment: "domain1" will be out of my control so there would be point having the username and password in the simplexml call as the user could just read the plain text user/pw